# Best way to change multiple properties with WPF bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a user control containing a text box and a label, the label display the length of the input text (with some formatting). I want to change the background color of the text box if the text is longer than 160 characters.

I was thinking of achieving this with bindings, but since the length of the text contain tag to be replaced I'm not willing to have 2 different binding making the same computing.
I don't succeed in changing

I can think of three way to achieves this :

1) create a hidden label with all tags replaced in his text, then have two simple converter to bind display the message length and change the background color. 3 converter for such a basic task seems too much to me.

2) Use the text_changed event to do the work. This work but it seems to me its not the way to do things in WPF.

3) Use a multibinding and pass my form as a source, this should work but looks too much 'god object' approach to me.

What do you think of that ? Am I missing a cleaner/simpler solution ?

Any suggestion is welcome, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "I was thinking of achieving this with bindings, but since the length of the text contain tag to be replaced I'm not willing to have 2 different binding making the same computing. I don't succeed in changing" and post some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another property `TBBackColor`, and bind your textbox `BackgroundColor` to it.
Something like:

```
Public System.Windows.Media.Brush TBBackColor
{
   get
   {
      return (TBText.Length>160)? new SolidColorBrush(Color.Red):  new SolidColorBrush(Color.White);
   }
}
```

And remember in your `TBText` property (if that is the one bind to your `TextBox`: `Text`) you need to raise propertychanged event for `TBBackColor` too.

Answer (score 0):

Using a converter is a good idea in this case, but you won't need multiple converters. Instead, we define one converter with multiple **parameters**:

```
public class TextBoxValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter as string))
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid arguments specified for the converter.");

        switch (parameter.ToString())
        {
            case "labelText":
                return string.Format("There are {0} characters in the TextBox.", ((string)value).Count());
            case "backgroundColor":
                return ((string)value).Count() > 20 ? Brushes.SkyBlue : Brushes.White;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid paramater specified for the converter.");
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then in your XAML you use it like this:

```
<TextBox Name="textBox" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource converter}, ConverterParameter=backgroundColor}"/>
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=textBox, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource converter}, ConverterParameter=labelText}"/>
```